# C# | SharpDX.XInput | How to detect if a button on the controller was pressed once and is not getting hold down

Tags: c#, sharpdx, gamepad, xinput

Lately i tried creating a XBOX 360 Controller Driver.
I need to detect if a button is pressed or held down. So if you hold down it also calls a specific function once just as if u would press the button once.
Here is my code (i found this solution on another post but it didn't work for me)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SharpDX.XInput;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Windows_XBOX_Controller_Driver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

        private static Controller controller;
        private State stateNew;
        private State stateOld;
        private int x, y;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Setup();
        }

        private void loop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!enabledcb.Checked)
            {
                return;
            }
            //
            stateNew = controller.GetState();
            ///////////////////////////////////
            x = stateNew.Gamepad.RightThumbX;
            y = stateNew.Gamepad.RightThumbY;

            x /= 1000;
            y /= 1000;
            //////////////////////////////
            int movementX = x;
            int movementY = y;

            movementX *= (int)sensnud.Value;
            movementY *= (int)sensnud.Value;

            movementX /= 2;
            movementY /= 2;

            movementY *= -1;
            ////////////////////////
            if (x > buffernud.Value || x < -buffernud.Value)
            {
                Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + movementX, Cursor.Position.Y);
            }
            if(y > buffernud.Value || y < -buffernud.Value)
            {
                Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + movementY);
            }
            //buttons
            CheckButtons();
        }

        private void CheckButtons()
        {

            //a left click
            if (stateOld.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.LeftShoulder && stateNew.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.LeftShoulder)
            {
                LeftClick();
            }

            //b right click
            if (stateOld.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.RightShoulder && stateNew.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.RightShoulder)
            {
                RightClick();
            }

            //dpad up button sens up
            if (stateOld.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.DPadUp && stateNew.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.DPadUp)
            {
                sensnud.UpButton();
            }

            //dpad down button sens down
            if (stateOld.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.DPadDown && stateNew.Gamepad.Buttons == GamepadButtonFlags.DPadDown)
            {
                sensnud.DownButton();
            }
            stateOld = stateNew;
        }

        private void LeftClick()
        {
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(0x02 | 0x04, (uint)X, (uint)Y, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        private void RightClick()
        {
            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            mouse_event(0x08 | 0x10, (uint)X, (uint)Y, 0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        private void LoadController()
        {
            controller = new Controller(UserIndex.One);
            if(!controller.IsConnected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "It seems like there is no XBOX 360 Controller connected via USB!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void updateLoop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xlbl.Text = "Offset X: " + x;
            ylbl.Text = "Offset Y: " + y;
        }

        private void applybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loop.Interval = (int)updatenud.Value;
        }

        private void Setup()
        {
            LoadController();
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code you can still hold down the buttons and it will spam the click functions or whatever is being called.

I also tried using a 'pressed' Boolean that is being set to true when pressed and to false when not pressed. And it only does the call when 'pressed' is == false.

Didn't work either.

Do you have any other solution for that problem ?

Sorry if this is a bad Question. I read the rules and tips for questions and i searched for duplicates but didn't find any except for the one i got the first solution from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have any other solution for that problem?

[Here](https://github.com/EmperorAiman/harry-potter-game/blob/master/SharedSource/Main/Utils/KeyPress.cs)'s a class I wrote the other day for another Engine. But I figured it would apply equally well to any other engine. I hope this helps you:

Basically, it checks if the key is *held* in the current frame and *not held* in the last frame. They key states are stored in a Dictionary

Here's the important part:

```
public bool IsKeyPress(Keys key)
{
    bool isCurrentlyPressed = WaveServices.Input.KeyboardState.IsKeyPressed(key);
    bool previouslyReleased = this.previousKeyStates[key] == ButtonState.Release;

    this.previousKeyStates[key] = isCurrentlyPressed ? ButtonState.Pressed : ButtonState.Release;

    return  isCurrentlyPressed && previouslyReleased;
}
```

Comment: Thx that's she same way i found out on my own til now but thx anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already
Dumb mistake: I forgot to invert the first condition in the if clauses for the button presses